# I encountered a Knapsack-like problem on maximizing the weight of polynomial combinations. Is this problem NP-complete?

Tags: polynomials, optimization, constraints

Let $n$ be a natural number $\geq 2$ and for each $i = 1 \ldots k$
let $P_i(x)$ be a polynomial modulo $x^n - 1$ with non-negative integer coefficients.
The *weight* $w(P(x))$ of a polynomial $P(x)$ is the number of non-vanishing terms in $P(x)$.

**Problem:** Maximize the polynomial weight of

$\sum_{i=1}^k x^{t_i} \cdot P_i(x)$ modulo  $x^n - 1$

subject to $t_i \geq 0$ for $i = 1 \ldots k$ and

$\sum_{i=1}^k w(P_i(x)) \leq m$.

**Note 1.** Non-negative coefficients make sure that no term vanishes under summation of polynomials.
For this purpose, the given polynomials may as well have coefficients among $\{ 0, 1 \}$.

**Note 2.** Mostly $m \leq n$. My special interest is $m = n$.

The posed problem looks much the same as the *Knapsack problem*.
However, there are fundamental differences:

First, the maximal weight of a polynomial combination, $n$,
is built in *physically* as polynomials are taken modulo $x^n - 1$.

Second, the combination "coefficients" $x^{t_i}$ aren't weight factors:
individually, they do not change the weight of the polynomial to which it is assigned.

The above maximizing problem is a translation of a purely combinatorial problem in an $n$ by $n$ board: choose any n locations. By cyclically shifting some columns up or down, the chosen set may take a different shape.
The problem is, then, to find shifting amounts for each involved column maximizing the number of rows involved with the set.

Call this a *vertical (V-)optimization*. There is a similar process of *horizontal (H-)optimization*.

A fundamental result (proven for n up to 37) is that applying an H-optimization on a V-optimized set yields a transversal of the columns. A dual result holds for reasons of symmetry.

Cyclically shifting columns, then rows, is a process called *shuffling*. It is *notoriously good* at randomizing a board filled with digits (in whatever base) and finally delivers a rich family of encryption- or hash-procedures.

NP-completeness of the basic operation would be a *very* welcome property.